# How to parse data through a button from one component to another

Tags: reactjs

Hello I wanna know if is possible to Parse data from a button from a component to another component I know you can parse data in the following way:

```
<Component data = {data} />
```

But I wanna send it through a button because I need to change of "page" when I send the data if that makes sense ?

I did try the following (Is just an example):

```
const sendData= () => {
    <Component data = {data} />
    history.push("/sendData");
  };

<Button onClick={sendData} >Click to send data</Button>
```

I got in return the following output:

[image]

As you can see I was sending some data and got undefined in return, I did a similar question before but didn't got a proper answer and haven't find a way to do it.

Any tips, help, documentation is welcome.

Edit: This is what I wanna send ->

[image]

I wanna send all the data from a variable that hold that data to another page so I can use it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to communicate between two components where you cannot send props.

you have two options:

1. Use a common state between the two pages (components) . You may either lift up the state or use a "not-so-local" state like react context
2. If you have react-router setup, you can also pass data in the history location object like so and later read it using useLocation hook

in first component:

```
const location = {
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}

<Link to={location}/>
<Redirect to={location}/>
history.push(location)
history.replace(location)
```

in other component:

```
let location = useLocation();
let state = location.state ;
```

here is the documentation https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

Comment: I'm a bit confuse isn't location used to check where you at/where you want to go/ where you were ?

Comment: @ReactPotato no it is used to check where you are

Comment: Yeah that's not what I wanna do sorry, I want to parse data Through a button. History is there because when I click the button it moves me to another location and I wanna parse the data to that other location.

Comment: Yes it is going to work for your usecase. You will push some data in location from first page and read it in another page. This is exactly what you want. Just try it

Comment: This worked I really don't understand how it did work... this is very confusing now hahaha wow thanks man. Like I don't understand how it keep track of something so vague.

Comment: This is what I did: 

`const location = {
  pathname: '/Crear_Pedidos',
  data: studentsID
}`

and then on the second component: `let location = useLocation();
  let data = location.data;`  I do not understand how it keep track of that like is super vague how it does even know is called location and has a `.data` from another component when on the first component I did not even use the `useLocation();` Anyways thank you very much this will help me a lot.